# Separate City , State and Zipcode from Address SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to separate the City State and Zip Code from the Adress Column which looks like below.

Some times the City name might be missing or State or Zipcode.

Some times there will be only City,State and Zip in the Adress Column.

Please do help me to resolve this issue.

```
Adress                           
PO BOX 28087 RALEIGH, NC 27611      
PO BOX 671 NASHVILLE, TN 37202
```

Answer (score 0):

Amrutha,
please do mention whether this address you are saying is in text form or you have a sort of form field for entering these...

Anyway, if it's in text form, I mean if these fields are held together as a single string, then SQL will not help. You have to use some sort of text extraction script for that (e.g. perl, awk).

Comment: Yes, these fields held together as single string. Colud you please explain me how can i make use of extraction script. But i need to resolve the issue in SSMS2008.

Comment: sry, can't help u in this regard...As far as i know sql language mainly used in popular dbms platform including mssql can't handle this sort of things. U hav to use general purpose languages for that(eg. C, Java) where u would be embedding your sql codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Cities varchar(200)
declare @Count int
declare @Adress varchar(52)
set @Adress = '5129 TWISTED WILLOW CREEDMOOR NC'
declare @i int
set @i = 0
declare @j int
set @j = 1
set @Count = 0
declare @city varchar(20)
set @city = '' 
set @Cities = 'RALEIGH.CARY.FOUR OAKS.CREEDMOOR'
while(@i < =LEN (@cities))
begin
  if(SUBSTRING(@cities,@i,1) = ',')
  set @count = @count+1
     set @i = @i+1
end
while(@j <=5)
begin
declare @s varchar(20)
set @s = PARSENAME(@cities,@j)
  if(PATINDEX('%'+@s+'%',@Adress ) >0)
  set @city = PARSENAME(@cities,@j)

  set @j = @j +1
end


select @city
```

I found above solution but i should add all city names to the string @cities.
Is their any other way of doing it easily?

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information, or post a new question.